# Determining the calling div in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a jquery function that returns the html for a randomized advertisement.

```
function getAd() {
    document.write( '<div>Some randomized ad html</div>' );
}
```

To insert the ad, I have this in my html file:

```
<div><script>getAd();</script></div>
```

This works, however, I'm trying to replace the document.write() code with something safer, like append(). So I'm trying this:

```
function getAd() {
    $(this).append( '<div>Some randomized ad html</div>' );
}
```

However, $(this) is the window and not the div.

I also tried this:

```
function getAd(elem) {
    $(elem).append( '<div>Some randomized ad html</div>' );
}
```

And in the html, I pass this:

```
<div><script>getAd(this);</script>
```

But once again, $(elem) is a window rather than the div. (In both of these cases, I get an "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined" error.)

I realize I can assign an id to the div and then pass the id to the getAd() function, but I have hundreds of these calls on the website (and sometimes several on the same page) and I would prefer not to have to assign and then pass an id every time I call this function.

Is there a way the calling function can determine the calling element so it can append the html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a common attribute (*or a class*) to all your elements:

```
<div random-ad>
```

And then, call your function using `$.each()`:

```
function getAd(elem) {
    $(elem).append( '<div>Some randomized ad html</div>' );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[random-ad]').each(function(){
        getAd(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Or `data-random-ad`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.